# Azure website not able to communicate to the third party API

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-cloud-services

Team,

I have recently migrated my azure classic portal resources to CSP subscription. I have successfully converted my azure cloud service to azure app website in the CSP subscription. But there is one thing i am not able connect. Its the third party API When we had the cloud service we had a .pfx uploaded to azure and in the code we use to create a uri which consists of the certifcate key + certificate secret key.

The certificate key is got directly  from web.config. But the certificate secret key is got from EncryptedSettings.Appsettings("SecretKeyName").

This is basically got from the encrypted app setting done earlier by 
https://eren.ws/2014/02/04/encrypting-the-web-config-file-of-an-azure-cloud-service/

But i am not sure what way should we implement on Azure website.

I have tried implementing the same but unfortunately it seems the secret key retrieval technique for cloud service is not the same as in the azure web app service.

When i debug the azure web site i can see that it gives the error as.

Failed to decrypt using provider ‘CustomProvider’. Error message from the provider: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: keyObject

Can anyone please guide me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than storing secrets in your config, you may wish instead to store them Azure KeyVault (which also gives you secret management capabilities etc) and then load the secrets at runtime.

KeyVault documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/

Specifically how to use keyvault with azure websites:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-use-from-web-application

And these days, don't bother with manual authentication to use  keyvault, instead use "Managed Service Identity", here's a tutorial:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/resources/samples/app-service-msi-keyvault-dotnet/

Interestingly the second tutorial does mention specifically using certificates for the purposes of authentication (against keyvault), you may wish to use this technique for yourself as a simplified way to get direct access to your certificate.

Comment: thanks Alex. That was helpful. I will take a look at the articles mentioned and let you now.

Comment: Cool, glad to be of assistance.

Comment: Hello alex...have gone through the steps one by one as per your second link. one problem here is that i am not able to upload the exisiting pfx certifcate with the password. It gives the error as invalid certifcate r wrong password. However, i am able to associate the same pfx certifcate to the app service. Am not sure of this peculair behaviour? Any idea on this phenomenon?

Comment: Interesting, is the error you see when you get to this point? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-use-from-web-application#add-code-to-your-web-app-to-use-the-certificate

Comment: Re-reading the links, bearing in mind the second tutorial is about using a certificate to authenticate against keyvault. Rather than specifically for using the certificate for your own purposes. If you're using it to store a certificate directly I'm not sure if it'll support using a password, as I'd guess the app service needs to know the password to be able to add it to the site's store? But I'm unsure, perhaps a good seperate question if you go down that route to gain more exposure on stackoverflow, on the other hand using keyvault for storage is what it's made for.

Comment: ok..just forgot to tell you. I had this error while uploading via powershell.           Import-AzureKeyVaultCertificate : Unsupported key size (1024). Supported sizes are [2048, 3072, 4096]. Guess I will put this as a separate question.

Comment: Ah very interesting! I'm guessing it's considering 1024 too weak these days? I don't see 1024 mentioned in this list https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-service-limits however that's for key sizes rather than certificates... I believe certs are composed of keys underneath https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/about-keys-secrets-and-certificates#key-vault-certificates yeah perhaps better as a separate question.

Comment: Hi Alex, just one general question. Suppose i know the client secret of the certifcate...is it still mandatoryto use the client certifcate in your Azure AD( especially if there is a slight difference in implementing)

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure I understand, my understanding of the the client secret (password) is too allow a machine / process to authenticate with AzureAD so it can be a service principal (service account). A client certificate is just like a long password in this scenario, except it has the benefit of being able to be managed in your certificate store. (I'm likely oversimplifying this a little).